# How to launch BioImageXD on mac?

Tags: python, macos

Hi I am trying to the launch the file BioImageXD.py. I followed all of the following instruciton, but nothing appears. The instructions are:

add paths of VTK and ITK libraries to
the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. These are:

```
${BXD_PATH}/Libraries/
${BXD_PATH}/Libraries/python2.7/site-packages/vtkbxd/
${BXD_PATH}/Libraries/vtk-5.6/
${BXD_PATH}/Libraries/InsightToolkit/

For example add following lines to your .bash_profile file:
BXD_PATH="Put your path to BioImageXD here"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:${BXD_PATH}/Libraries/:${BXD_PATH}/Libraries/python2.7/site-packages/vtkbxd/:${BXD_PATH}/Libraries/vtk-5.6/:${BXD_PATH}/Libraries/InsightToolkit/
```

Comment: That looks like only a subset of [the directions on the wiki](http://www.bioimagexd.net/wiki/index.php?title=Build_in_Mac_OSX). Did you complete the rest?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem, in my case I was  missing the prerequisites CMake and SWIG. Also it seems like you didn't follow the setup instructions thoroughly. please [check them out](http://www.bioimagexd.net/wiki/index.php?title=Build_in_Mac_OSX)